# Defining a function inside a conditional

Tags: php

Snippet 1 works. Snippet 2 doesn't. Why?

1.

```
foo();

function foo()
{
    // do soemething
}
```

2.

```
foo();

if(!function_exists("foo"))
{
    function foo()
    {
        // do soemething
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php:

> Functions need not be defined before
>   they are referenced, **except when a
>   function is conditionally defined** [...]
>   Its definition must be processed prior
>   to being called.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to execute foo() *before* testing to see whether it's defined or not (and subsequently defining it)

```
if(!function_exists("foo")) 
{ 
    function foo() 
    { 
        // do soemething 
    } 
} 

foo();
```